# Strange Conversion double to int

Tags: java, swift, integer, double

I recently came up with a small issue in ios swift when converting Double to Int.

```
var myDoubleValue: Double = 10.2
var newInt = Int(myDoubleValue * 100) //1019
```

There I am multiplying 10.2 by 100 and NOT getting the expected value (1020) and instead 1019...

But works correct in most of the cases as follows

```
var myDoubleValue: Double = 10.3
var newInt = Int(myDoubleValue * 100) //1030
```

Also I further tested it with Java and the same issue there as well..

```
double myDoubleValue = 10.2;
int myIntValue1 = (int)(myDoubleValue * 100); //1019
```

I could overcome the issue by performing 'round' before convert to Int as follows...

```
var myDoubleValue: Double = 10.2
var newInt = Int(round(myDoubleValue * 100)) //1020
```

But this goes in to something I don't want if the value is having 3 decimal places as follows, because it's rounding at that time (10.206 ---> 1021)

Comment: First, the displayed value is just that, it is not the entire value, use formatting to see more digits. Second, 10.2 or 10.3 can not be exactly represented in a base2 floating point number so results can be very slightly different than expected. Third, it might help if you spent some time learning about floating point numbers.

Comment: Strongly related: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A displayed value is just that, it is not the entire value, use formatting to see more digits. 10.2 or 10.3 can not be exactly represented in a base2 floating point number so results can be very slightly different than expected.

Here is an example that shows what is happening:

```
var myDoubleValue1: Double = 10.2
print(String(format: "myDoubleValue1: %.17f", myDoubleValue1))
// myDoubleValue1: 10.19999999999999929

var myDoubleValue2: Double = 10.3
print(String(format: "myDoubleValue2: %.17f", myDoubleValue2))
// myDoubleValue2: 10.30000000000000071
```

Note that 10.2 converts to a floating point Double as slightly **below** 10.2 and the will be truncated down.

Note that 10.3 converts to a floating point Double as slightly **above** 10.3 and the will **not** be truncated down.

If exact decimal math, such as in a calculator or when dealing with money, is required use `NSDecimalNumber`

Answer (score 2):

This is the result of *round up/truncation errors*. Actually,

```
  myDoubleValue = 10.2
```

is something like

```
  myDoubleValue = 10.1999999999999
```

so

```
 myDoubleValue * 100 = 1019.999999999
```

and after being **trimmed** to `int` you have `1019`. A better practice is to *round up* rather than *trim*:

```
 double myDoubleValue = 10.2;
 int myIntValue1 = (int)(myDoubleValue * 100 + 0.5); // note "+ 0.5"
 System.out.println(myIntValue1);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Java answer**

This is because the `double` and `float` types and wrappers do not guarantee precise values when operated upon.

In Java, the recommended idiom for what you're looking for is:

```
BigDecimal myDoubleValue = new BigDecimal("10.2");
int myInt = myDoubleValue.multiply(new BigDecimal("100")).intValue();
System.out.println(myInt);
```

**Output**

```
1020
```

Comment: In Swift and Objective-C there is the `NSDecimalNumber` class that handles decimal numbers exactly.

Comment: @zaph thanks for the comment. I know nearly nothing about Objective-C / Swift, so I couldn't answer on that part :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to round up a small amount of error but you want to round down other wise.

You can do this

```
double d = 10.199999;
long l = (long) (d * 100 + 0.01); // l = 10.20

double d = 10.206;
long l = (long) (d * 100 + 0.01); // l = 10.20
```